# SQL select statements not matching on certain rows

Tags: postgresql

I am running a Postgresql database with docker-compose, using the image `postgres:10-alpine`. For some reason, the database is unable to select certain rows based on string comparison. For example, this query works as expected:

```
peertube=# SELECT id, "preferredUsername" FROM actor WHERE "preferredUsername"='user1';
  id   | preferredUsername 
-------+-------------------
 38793 | user1             
(1 row)
```

However, the same query is not working for another user:

```
peertube=# SELECT id, "preferredUsername" FROM actor WHERE "preferredUsername"='user2';
 id | preferredUsername 
----+-------------------
(0 rows)
```

The user definitely exists, and the query works if I use `ILIKE` instead of `=`:

```
peertube=# SELECT id, "preferredUsername" FROM actor WHERE "preferredUsername" ILIKE 'user2'; 
  id   | preferredUsername 
-------+-------------------
 41576 | user2
(1 row)
```

What could be the reason for this wrong behaviour? I suspected it might have something to do with the encoding, but `SHOW SERVER_ENCODING` and `SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING` both show UTF8. I also tried to export the data and import it into a fresh database. That fixed the problem for a few days, but it came back after that.

I'm happy about any possible solutions or debugging ideas.

Edit: Some more queries, it works with trim() in the WHERE clause:

```
peertube=# SELECT "preferredUsername", "preferredUsername" FROM actor WHERE trim("preferredUsername")='mailab';
 preferredUsername | btrim  |               md5
-------------------+--------+----------------------------------
 mailab            | mailab | 3d83ba6a9e5391c0c4d0253fbb2b01aa
```

However, this still seems weird because if there is whitespace, the hash of the field should be different. In fact, the md5 is the same:

```
peertube=# SELECT "preferredUsername", md5("preferredUsername"), md5('mailab') FROM actor WHERE trim("preferredUsername")='mailab';
 preferredUsername |               md5                |               md5
-------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------
 mailab            | 3d83ba6a9e5391c0c4d0253fbb2b01aa | 3d83ba6a9e5391c0c4d0253fbb2b01aa
```

Edit 2:  Length is the same with or without trim, so that seems to rule out the whitespace theory:

```
peertube=# SELECT "preferredUsername", length("preferredUsername"), length(trim("preferredUsername")) FROM actor WHERE trim("preferredUsername")='mailab';
 preferredUsername | length | length
-------------------+--------+--------
 mailab            |      6 |      6
```

Edit 3: Details of the affected table: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1840320

Edit 4: Someone suggested the `get_byte()` function to check that there are no unexpected utf8 characters. And in fact, every single character corresponds to an ascii value in the range 97-122.

Comment: Any white spaces after the user2  value in the table ? Have you tried trimming the value in the table ?

Comment: Could be a corrupted index due to binary-migrating the index across systems with incompatible libc collations. The weird thing is you fix it by a dump-reload and the problem comes back after a few days?

Comment: @armitage Good idea, the query is working with that. But it is still weird because the hashes are the same (see my edit).

Comment: @DanielVérité Exactly, I dumped to plain text, and after that everything was fine. It is possible that this is some kind of application bug.

Comment: Questions about the corrupted index theory: once it happens, is it always reproducible? Is the column indexed? If the failing query is run with `SET enable_indexscan to off`, does it give the same result? What is the collation of the column?

Comment: Yes, the problem happens consistently. The column is not indexed, and collation seems to be the default (see my latest edit for full table info). The `enable_indexscan` command doesnt change anything.

Comment: Hmm it is indexed: `"actor_preferred_username_server_id" UNIQUE, btree ("preferredUsername", "serverId")`

Answer (score 1):

I would check and see if there are any white spaces after the Value 'User2' in the database.

I would also look at the application inserting the data and if possible profile the data stream before insertion to determine if the application is incorrectly adding white spaces.

Alternatively I would look at the source of the 'User2' and ensure that the source does not contain white spaces.

Comment: Do you know any command that I can use to show whitespace in the database field? I am already talking with the application developer to debug this.

Comment: I'm not a PostgreSql expert but could you get the length of the data in the field and compare to the length of the trimmed data in the field? If there is a difference you have white space. I've also seen this with hidden control characters.

Comment: Turns out length is exactly the number of visible characters, so that seems to rule out the whitespace theory (see my last edit).